# Options for plumbing/drainage in an outbuilding? (Ontario, Canada)

Tags: plumbing

What are some of the options available for having plumbing in an outbuilding in Ontario, Canada?

My house is attached to city water/sewer. I am planning a build for an Accessory Dwelling Unit in the backyard and I'm trying to figure out how to get running water and drainage to the building but my searches aren't coming up with much as I don't know what kind of parts/pumps/etc to search for.

The house is higher than the backyard by 2-4m and the ADU will be anywhere from 10m to 30m from the house.

Comment: does the land slope?

Comment: Is the city sewer your current drain lines are connected to in the street in front? Do your current drains flow by gravity or do you have a tank and a lift pump? What is the difference in elevation between the site for the proposed ADU and your house?

Comment: @Jasen a bit, but the house is higher than the ADU

Comment: @JimStewart sewer in street, yes. gravity, not sure, but I believe so. the lowest drain in the ADU is probably 10 feet or more lower than the basement of house and up to 100 feet away depending on final position